# What does it mean when APS editors ask us to "list first page" for some refferences?

Tags: publications, paper-submission, editors

Basically the title. I don't understand what the editors are asking from us? Are they asking us to make a list out of the first page of these references, e.g. by copying and pasting them into a file and then submit it??

Needless to say, English isn't my first language. Any help is appreciated.
[image: A screenshot from the proofread file]

Comment: I'd guess that you used the wrong (or no) page number for the two references in the list of references.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe they mean that the complete citation in the back of the paper should include the page number of the reference in the journal/book where it was published.

For instance, in APA style:

Einstein, A. (1918). Prinzipielles zur allgemeinen Relativitätstheorie. *Annalen der Physik*, 360(4), 241-244.

Here 241-244 are the page numbers of the journal where the paper was published, and 241 is the first page.

Comment: I think you are probably right. However, my references already had a page number. And I had used Mendeley to automatically generate the Bibtex file so I don't think the formatting had any issues either. (O_o)

Comment: I've seen some physics journals with the (weird, in my opinion) convention of listing **only** the first page, not the last page.  I don't remember whether this was an APS journal.

Comment: This is surely it. However, I have submitted to an APS journal in the past and didn’t get this request. That being said, it was rejected within 10 hours!!

Comment: @AndreasBlass APS journals generally don't list the range. I guess not doing so used to save some space and paper. These days APS publish so many papers that it's not really a page number anymore, it's a "paper number", if you will. So one paper reference will have "page" number 092101 and the next 092102, with individual pages labeled e.g. 092102-3. Personally, as a reader, I don't see much use in having the page range there anyway, so I don't find it weird.